# spark scala type mismatch with zipwithIndex in groupbykey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

I am trying to test groupByKey to find nth highest score of a subject

my data looks like this

```
scala> a
res176: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[263] at map at <console>:51

scala> a.take(10).foreach{println}
(data science,DN,US,28,98,SMITH,data science)
(maths,DN,US,28,92,SMITH,maths)
(chemistry,DN,US,28,94,SMITH,chemistry)
(physics,DN,US,28,88,SMITH,physics)
(data science,DN,UK,25,93,JOHN,data science)
(maths,DN,UK,25,91,JOHN,maths)
(chemistry,DN,UK,25,95,JOHN,chemistry)
(physics,DN,UK,25,90,JOHN,physics)
(data science,DN,CA,29,67,MARK,data science)
(maths,DN,CA,29,68,MARK,maths)

scala>
```

so for the first row "data science" as string is key and "DN,US,28,98,SMITH,data science" is value as a string

now I want to find 2nd highest using group by

```
scala> a.groupByKey().flatMap(rec=>{ val max = rec._2.toList.map(x=>x.split(',')(3).toFloat).distinct.sortBy(x=>(-x)).zipWithIndex.filter(x=>x._2==2).toMap.keys
     | rec._2.toList.filter{x=>x.split(',')(3).toFloat==max}
     | }).take(15).foreach{println}

scala>
```

I am getting nothing here

if i run this hard-coded i get value

```
scala> a.groupByKey().flatMap(rec=>{ val max = "98"
     | rec._2.toList.sortBy(x=>(-x.split(',')(3).toFloat)).takeWhile(rec=> max.contains(rec.split(',')(3)))}).take(15).foreach{println}
DN,IND,26,98,XMAN,maths
DPS,US,28,98,XOMAN,chemistry
DN,US,28,98,SMITH,data science
```

also this gives me value

```
scala> a.groupByKey().flatMap(rec=>{ rec._2.toList.map(x=>x.split(',')(3).toFloat).distinct.sortBy(x=>(-x)).zipWithIndex.filter(x=>x._2==2).map(_._1)}).take(15).foreach{println}
94.0
92.0
95.0
93.0
```

some more complex code gives me output

```
scala> a.groupByKey().flatMap(rec=>{ val max = rec._2.toList.map(x=>x.split(',')(3).toFloat).distinct.sortBy(x=>(-x)).take(1)
     | rec._2.toList.sortBy(x=>(-x.split(',')(3).toFloat)).takeWhile(rec=> max.contains(rec.split(',')(3).toFloat))}).take(15).foreach{println}
DN,IND,26,98,XMAN,maths
DPS,UK,25,96,SOMK,physics
DPS,US,28,98,XOMAN,chemistry
DN,US,28,98,SMITH,data science
```

looks like there is some data type mismatch when i am using zipwithindex.
Can some one help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a type mismatch due to `.toMap.keys`. In the result, val `max` is of type Iterable[Float], because method `keys` returns Iterable[A].

On of the solution would be an addition of `head` at the end of `max` calculation:

```
  val max = rec._2.toList
    .map(x => x.split(',')(3).toFloat)
    .distinct
    .sortBy(x => (-x))
    .zipWithIndex
    .filter(x => x._2 == 2)
    .toMap
    .keys
    .head
```

Basically, `head` will return a value of type `Float`. Then this code should at least compare equal types `x.split(',')(3).toFloat == max`.

Although, calling `head` is not safe method. It may throw an exception, if in your case a `filter` function can return empty list. Then such exception will be thrown:

`java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator`

Once it work for concrete data sample, you can think to refactor this code to work with Set maybe. Instead of `head` do `.keys.toSet` and compare like you did for other examples using `max.contains(rec.split(',')(3))`

Comment: Thanks Alexey , your answer helped, I got result after .head. Just need some more clarification , when I use toSet again I am not getting any value  a.groupByKey().flatMap(rec=>{ val max = rec._2.toList.map(x=>x.split(',')(3).toFloat).distinct.sortBy(x=>(-x)).zipWithIndex.filter(x=>x._2==2).toMap.keys.toSet
rec._2.toList.sortBy(x=>(-x.split(',')(3).toFloat)).takeWhile(rec=> max.contains(rec.split(',')(3).toFloat))}).take(15).foreach{println}

Comment: You are welcome. `toSet` should also work. I have a filling that `takeWhile` is not really what you want. Basically, `.takeWhile` will stop filtering a collection, once its predicate function returns `false` for the first time. Event though a collection may have some elements, which will be `true` according to the `takeWhile` predicate. There is an example for just Scala collections, not Spark: `List(3f,2,1).zipWithIndex.toMap.keys.toSet.takeWhile(x => x < 3)
res4: Set[Float] = Set()`. Try to use `filter` instead of `takeWhile`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, .takeWhile will stop filtering a collection and that is the reason why this is happening as first record is != max so it is not giving me result. Your answer really helped me. Thanks for taking out your time and helping me out. Please keep it up !!  Hoping this is what i should do escape java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator 
.
val max1 = (if (max.isEmpty) 0.0 else max.head)
rec._2.toList.sortBy(x=>(-x.split(',')(3).toFloat)).filter{rec=> max1==(rec.split(',')(3).toFloat)}}).take(15).foreach{println}